# MongoDB create a pointer for one field to another field in a different collection

Tags: mongodb

I am not sure exactly how to phrase the question, so I will try to ask with an example. I am using Mongo 4.0

Suppose I have two collections. `Data` and `Users`. The items in the `User` collection are:

```
{
  username: 'test',
  avatar: 'https://linktoavatar'
}
```

And the `Data` collection contains:

```
{
  data: ...
  otherfields...
  username: 'test',
  avatar: 'https://linktoavatar'
  comments: [
    username: 'test',
    avatar: 'https://linktoavatar',
    comment: 'some comment'
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is create a pointer between `Data.avatar` and `Data.comment.avatar` to the link in `User.avatar`. This way, if the user changes their avatar (updates the `User` collection), it will reflect the change in all relevant fields in the `Data` collection.

How can I do this?

Comment: "How can I do this?" - You can't do this. Unless you normalize your data and store `user_id` in your data documents (instead of username/avatar)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not support **cascading**.

It must be addressed at application level. In PHP, [Doctrine MongoDB ODM](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb-odm.html) offers a [cascading](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/reference-mapping.html#cascading-operations) functionality.  Probably you will find something like that written in the language you are using.